# Why do coffeescript/jquery functions not trigger on DOM elements loaded via ajax, and how to fix?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a coffeescript function that toggles a css class when a link is clicked.

```
#coffeescript
jQuery ->
  $(".toggle-link").click ->
    $(this).toggleClass "selected"

#view
<%= link_to "toggle", my_path, class: "toggle-link" %>
```

This works fine.

But if I move the link into an ajaxified partial, e.g. for pagination, the jquery toggle stops working.

Why is this?

And how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic elements :

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).on 'click', ".toggle-link", ->
    $(this).toggleClass "selected"
```

(replace `document` with the container of your pages for better efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery delegate function istead of click. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

$('#paren-element-id').delegate('.toggle-link', click', function yourCallback(){});